# create multiple tables in an adobe air database

Tags: database, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I want to create 2 tables in a single adobe air database.

i am using Adobe flash builder with the import flash.data.*;

I tried initializing the statement below. it give me the error on creating the second table.

Do i have to use other API so that

```
private function db_opened(e:SQLEvent):void {
    sqls.sqlConnection = sqlc;
    sqls.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT);";
    sqls.execute();
    sqls.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table2 ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT);";
    sqls.execute();

     }
```

**ERROR**
Error: Error #3106: Property cannot be changed while SQLStatement.executing is true.
    at Error$/throwError()
    at flash.data::SQLStatement/set text()

Answer (score 0):

Take Separate SQLStatements to execute these two different queries.

Because it doesn't allows you to change the text property of the SQLStatement while you are querying one query.

So simply use two different SQLStatement for executing two queries.